# Wolfram Kernel and Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wolfram-mathematica

I've got a python project that uses the wolframclient library that I want to deploy onto AWS elastic beanstalk.

I've tried installing Wolfram Engine through ssh, but wolframclient is having issues using the kernel even though the correct file path is given.

(WolframKernelException : Failed to communicate with kernel:/Wolfram/Executables/WolframKernel)

Any ideas on what the best way to go about this is?

Thanks